# Best way to print array/list in prolog without commas, brackets, or spacing?

Tags: arrays, list, prolog, output, swi-prolog

So I am just getting started and fooling around with prolog.

Suppose I have a list of numbers as such:

```
X = [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
```

and want to print those numbers to the screen without commas, spacing, or newlines like this:

```
?- write(X).
01011110
```

So far I have tried using write(X). which just prints the array, and I have fooled around with print_term using the pprint module but haven't had any success.

Right now i have a method to create a grid of 0's and 1's as such:

```
grid(0,[]).
grid(X,Y) :-
    X > 0, 
    X1 is X-1,
    random(0, 2, U),
    Y = [U|T],
    grid(X1,T).
```

The above method works as intended, just not getting the output i desire on printing. If it changes things, I do intend to turn this into a 2d grid eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all elements in the input are indeed numbers (or atoms), you can use builtin predicate [atomic_list_concat/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/2) :

```
?- X = [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0], atomic_list_concat(X,Y), write(Y).
01011110
```

If it were a matrix represented as a list of lists you could do something like this:

```
print_matrix([]).
print_matrix([Row|Rows]):-
  atomic_list_concat(Row, TRow),
  writeln(TRow),
  print_matrix(Rows).
```

sample test:

```
?- print_matrix([[1,0,0,1], [0,1,1,0]]).
1001
0110
```

Comment: @DevG: Thats the toplevel printing the bindings. If you don't want to get those bindings you can create a procedure with a single parameter (the input list)

Comment: @DevG: What apostrophes are you seeing ? If they are numbers there should be no apostrophes

Comment: Thanks for the help, going to try out that single param procedure with your advice.