# Alternative to maplist() without commas or brackets

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make a simple print of a list, without brackets or commas.
The idea is given multiple lists such as:

> X = [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], ...

They should print like this:

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 6 7 8 9 10

I have something like this:

```
printing(X) :- maplist(writeln, X).
```

Which gives:

> [1,2,3,4,5]
>
> [6,7,8,9,10]
>
> ....

I've also tried this:

```
printing(X):-
        atomic_list_concat(X, ' ', Y),
        write(Y).
```

But it doesn't work properly:

```
ERROR: Type error: `text' expected, found `[1,2,3,4]' (a list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56467627/12499839

Just made a small change in atomic_list_concat():

```
print_matrix([]).
print_matrix([Row|Rows]):-
  atomic_list_concat(Row, ' ' , TRow),
  writeln(TRow),
  print_matrix(Rows).
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).